# Algorithm to show how far away a value is from another

Tags: java, python, excel, algorithm, statistics

Disclaimer: This is a very very difficult question about mathematics and algorithms (in my opinion) - so respect to anyone who makes this. I admire you.

I would like to evaluate the performance of my employees. I would like to do this by measuring the following parameters as percentages of the amount of time they spend working:

```
1. % of Time spent working
2. % of Time spent in meetings
3. % of Time spent travelling
```

I have a "preferred" set of percentages for each of these. This represents the ideal time that I would LIKE my employees to spend their time.

```
% Time spent in Meetings -> 30%
% Time spent Travelling -> 10%
% Time Spent Working -> 60%

total time spent on activities: 100%
```

So in words, I would like my employees to spend 30% of their time in meetings, 10% time travelling and 60% on a desk working.

I would ALSO like to add weights to these different percentages. The weight would represent how "lenient" I am with each percentage being different to what I desire. In other words, how important I find it for each variable to be closest to the desired percentages (30, 10, 60). I would like to apply the weights on a scale of.1 to 10, 10 being most important, 1 being least important.

```
Meetings -> 3
Travelling -> 9
Working -> 5
```

So given the percentage of time spent by an employee, and the weight of the importance of the time spent being close to the desired time spent, I would like to generate an index between 0 and 100 where 100 is the perfect time percentages and 0 is the worst. So a score of 100 would give the "preferred" percentages:

```
% Time spent in Meetings -> 30%
% Time spent Travelling -> 10%
% Time Spent Working -> 60%
```

How I would try to approach this:

1. Find out what the minimum and maximum ratios are
2. Calculate a value to tell how far away each value is from the desired value using the minimum and maximum ratios. Make sure this value is in the ratio 0-1 (corresponding to 0-100)
3. Calculate a weighted average.

Comment: I'm assuming you know which language you're working in. Please remove the other tags.

Comment: @unknownUser This is an interesting question, but since it is about concepts it is off topic for SO; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. That said, the fundamental questions you need to answer are (1) how can one define "value" of an employee (e.g., how much money they make for you? how long they work for you? something else?), and (2) what can you observe *now* which is relevant for estimating value as in item 1. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying something which is kinda like the H-score.
H-score is a scored we use in digital pathology to measure tumor positivity for a maker and it is meant to weight the number of positive cells by their intensity.
It's:

```
1* (% of positive cells with score 1) + 2*(% of positive cells with score 2) + 3*(% of positive cells with score 3)
```

You could calculate the same as:

```
3*(1-% of difference between actual worked hourse and planned ones)
9*(1-% of difference between actual worked hourse and planned ones)
5*(1-% of difference between actual worked hourse and planned ones)
```

Don't forget to use absolute value when you compute the difference.
I used 1-% so that a difference of 0.8 (as planned 0.ì and worked 0.9) will result in a score of 0.2. This will work for the opposite situation too (planned 0.9 and worked 0.1).
In this way, who perfectly matches the planned hourse will have a score of 1700%.
Then just:

```
Score/Total weights = score between 0-100%.
```

Comment: Thank you this is good but there is an issue with this. If I calculate weight*(1-(%difference), if the actual worked hours is greater than the planned ones, I get a percent difference that is greater than 1. Like if I have an actual worked hours of 100 for just TRAVELLING, the calculation would be weight(1-(%diff) = 3(1-(abs(100-10)/10)) = 5(1-(10) = 5 * -9 = -45. -45 Is not on a scale of 0-1

Comment: wait, maybe I was not clear. When you calculate "1-%" it has to be in the interval 0-1.
So if he travels 100% insted 10% the formula is:

5*(1-(abs(0.1-1)) = 5*(1-0.9) = 5*(0.1) = 0.5